# Which is correct usage of equals method in java?

Tags: java

Simple question, which is correct way of using `equals`, also provide reasoning behind answer.

```
"Delta".equals(type)
```

or

```
type.equals("Delta")
```

Comment: Both are equally good.  The first one guarantees that you won't dereference a null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally

```
"Delta".equals(type)
```

is favored, as it is impossible to throw a `NullPointerException`.  That said, the other way is not "incorrect" as it is not in error with the Java Language Specification; however, it is just susceptible to failure *if* `(type == null)` is true.

The term "best practice" is used to differentiate a better choice from a correct, but inferior choice.  In this case `"Delta".equals(type)` is a best practice, to avoid the unnecessary guard code required to handle null pointer references.

Comment: I don't agree that it's best practice. Best practice is to make code as readable as possible and the second version expresses the intention better than the first. It's safer but more "geeky".

Comment: Readability is not a matter of visual presentation, but a matter of whether that presentation expresses the operations cleanly, without misleading contexts.  `X+1` and `1+X` are both equally readable, even though most would choose `X+1` first.  In this case, both expressions are `Object equals Object`, yet one ordering of that expression can keep your program from crashing.  Neither one is hiding what is happening through _clever optimization_.  Finally, keep in mind that __readable code is secondary to operational code__, even among the experts in code quality, they don't choose to error.

Comment: @EdwinBuck you don't need to choose the error. you can simply test for null first. Maybe some kind of Elvis operator support could simplify this in future.

Comment: @Puce, true, you could put a lot of "if this is null" tests in the code beforehand; but, if you care about readability, wouldn't it be more "readable" to compare once, instead of a check-and-then-compare?  http://www.ecomba.org/post/18247826192/emptying-the-cup Empty your cup, and then you can capture the core idea, then you can evaluate it as you have heard it.

Comment: I'm aware of that. And there is currently no satisfactory solution to it IMHO. But I still think it's not a "best practice" rather a matter of preference. Some like the first version for the reasons you mentioned, some prefer the second version for the reasons I mentioned. There are a lot of cases where you have to check for null anyway (where you don't test against a constant). Making a special case here is not necessary IMHO. And if you remember to call the equals method on the constant because of potential NPE, you could also remember to check for null with about the same thought.

Comment: And yes, it's noisy, but Java is quite a noisy language anyway. I hope we get more language constructs in future to reduce the noise.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head, it is one of perception.  In your humble opinion, there is no solution to the wordiness of a check-and-then-compare solution; however, in the provided answer there is a solution which is less wordy.  Perhaps there is some aspect of your opinion that is inconsistent or oblivious to answer before you?  There is no need for a new language construct to solve an issue which has a simple, clear, straight-forward solution: don't turn Java into ALGOL.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: "*`X+1` and `1+X` are both equally readable*"—disagree, it depends entirely on context.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  The first calls the compare method on a definitely non-null string, so it will not throw a NullPointerException, the second might if `type` is null

The sfirst version is "safer", the second "reads" more naturally

Comment: The other way-around, but I agree type.equals("Delta") expresses more the intention (you want to check if type is equal to Delta not if Delta is equal to type). That's why I usually prefer the second version.

Comment: Thanks, got my order confused